# Limiting distribution of the solution to the one-dimensional heat equation

Tags: limits, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Consider the one-dimensional heat equation  with initial boundary conditions given by

$$u_{t}=ku_{xx}, \ 0<x<L, \ t >0,$$

$$u_{x}(0,t)=u_{x}(L,t)=0,$$

$$u(x,0)=f(x).$$
Using separation of variables, eigenvalues, and eigenfunctions, I obtained the solution 
$$u=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}\cos\left ( \frac{n\pi x}{L} \right )\exp\left [ -kt \left ( \frac{n \pi}{L} \right )^2\right ].$$
The question asks what happens so the solution as $t \rightarrow \infty$.  More formally,

> Determine the temperature distribution as $t \rightarrow \infty.$

Clearly, $$\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}u=0.$$
This becomes $0$ because of the negative exponential.  However, my friends and I were talking and we don't think this makes that much sense, physically, at least.  Mathematically I see no problem.

Another reason I am slightly dubious about this answer is the fact that the next question asks about the temperature distribution as $t \rightarrow \infty$ with specific values of $L,k$ and $f(x).$  Again, the limit I obtained was $0.$

Am I not interpreting this correctly?  Can anyone give me some feedback?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've omitted $n=0$ from the summation, incorrectly, and that is what remains as $t\to\infty$. What happens is that the temperature distribution tends to a constant, the average of the initial condition, because the boundary conditions are insulating (no heat flow in or out).